# why we need to exclude node_modules in webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

below is a webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    output: { filename: "bundle.js" },
    resolve: { extensions: [".ts"] },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts/, use: "ts-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ }
           }
        ]
    }
};
```

I don't understand why we need to exclude node_modules when dealing with typescript files? Below is my points:

1-Firstly, nearly all packages are written in js not in ts, it is not going to harm if we include node_modules.

2-If we are referencing a package that is written in ts, we definitely want ts code to be compiled to js code, then we have to include node_modules to make sure everything works, don't we?

Comment: Won't it take forever to compile a project otherwise?

Comment: @zerkms  why it take forever to compile a project? for example, I just import React package in the index.ts, the webpack will only combine react js files with index.js

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @zerkms  I have tried it. But I want to know why it take forever to compile a project, because I must have a misunderstanding in it

Comment: Which source says you **have** to exclude them? https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader#configuration does not event do that...

Comment: @madflow  no sources say that, the webpack config file in my post is a project in my book. it does exclude node_modules, so I guess we have to do that too, and the other user here says if I don't exclude node_modules,  it take forever to compile a project . SO I guess I have to exclude?

Comment: The ratio is - that npm packages are already in a form - that they do not need any processing. That is why you exclude them from webpack. If you process them - it *could* result in a performance penalty.

Comment: "I guess I have to exclude" --- it's up to you. If you need to process something - you process something; if you don't - you don't. Don't implement something simply because a book says so, but implement something if you need it.

Comment: @madflow, isn't that webpack just link and bundle requires js package, what kind of processing it need to link the required js file to bundle.js? the required package is alread js file, just simply copy and paste then bundle.

Comment: @amjad Webpack is a dumb tool that will do what you tell it to do. If you have configured `babel-loader` to process `.js` and you tell that thing not to process something in dir `foo` - it will not do that. Not sure what you mean with "link" a required file, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-Firstly, nearly all packages are written in js not in ts, it is not going to harm if we include node_modules.

Excluding `node_modules` at the transpiling stage increases performance which could  otherwise get a hit.

> If we are referencing a package that is written in ts, we definitely want ts code to be compiled to js code, then we have to include node_modules to make sure everything works, don't we?

Yes, and *then* is the key here. Excluding `node_modules` at the transpiling stage doesn't prevent webpack from using its content at the bundling stage.

Comment: sorry I'm still confused,  how excluding node_modules at the transpiling stage increases performance , could you give me a scenario?

Comment: Suppose the helper used by webpack to transpile Typescript files (webpack itself doesn't do it) is searching for some .ts or .js file while resolving imports. The file cannot be found so there will be an error. If the helper looks for this file under `node_modules` then there will be a significant delay (because `node_modules` can be huge) before the error is triggered. Searching for files under `node_modules` is specifically mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) under the _How TypeScript resolves modules_ heading.